# iPhone memory doesnt free up after calling nil

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage, didreceivememorywarning

I am using Apple's ScrollingSuite for displaying a large scrollview with a number of large images.(768 x1024) The image of an imageview is set by

```
controller.numberImage.image = [self.contentList objectAtIndex:page];
```

where, numberImage is an UIImageView and controller is an object of the viewcontroller which I am adding in the scrollview. I am setting the image as nil when the page is scrolled out of view by

```
controller.numberImage.image = nil;
```

But the problem is my app runs out of memory receiving Memory Warning when scrolled through the images. Each time a new image is shown, I can see memory increasing in instruments tool (Memory Tag 70) which on googling turns out ImageIO. Please help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think self.contentList keeps a reference of the image in memory? Every references should be released in order to free an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the imageView ( `[controller.numberImage removeFromSuperview];` ), then adding it back before it is about to come into view ( `[controller addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.contentList objectAtIndex:page]]];` ) possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Various kinds of solution can be for such kinds of problem so...

1. I think you can remove the imageview like `[controller.numberImage removeFromSuperview]` and alloc the image again when you need the `UImageView`.it can be first solution.
2. At a time you can load 3 images if i explain then load the present image,previous image and  next image.thats mean if you want to see the image 2 load at a time three images,image 1,image 2,and image 3. when you will scroll to next image then load image 2,image 3 and image 4 and dealloc the image 1...and so on...vice versa for loading image previous image loading.
3. the worst solution is try to decrease the image resolution without changing the size of the image.